# HTML Table from jQuery .load() doesn't render in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, firefox, html-table

I have an HTML table I want to insert into multiple HTML pages. I've successfully used jQuery to do this, except in Firefox.

Here's an HTML file where I'm attempting to insert a table from another HTML file (this is just a simplified example, not the actual code I'm working with).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#TableContainer').load('IpsumTable.htm');    
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Here is my table</h2>
    <div id="TableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is meant to show a simple header with the table underneath. The `IpsumTable.htm` file includes just a simple HTML table, like so:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>WrittenName</th>
            <th>CommaCount</th>
            <th>Syllables</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Twelve</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2,254</td>
            <td>Two thousand two hundred fifty four</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1,000,000,000</td>
            <td>One billion</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>Seventeen</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox, the table isn't rendered. It just shows the pre-rendered HTML code:
    `��<table border="1" style="width: 562px"> <tbody> <tr> <th align="left">`... etc.

Any ideas why this is? Those two mysterious question mark icons (��) preceding the table code show up on the page, which may be a clue, but I don't know what they mean or where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like firefox have some trouble opening .htm-files.

I found a questiom on mozillas support forum, maybe some of those answers might help you :)
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973637

Also it seems better to go with .html-files than .htm

Answer (score 0):

A few years back there has been a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5849) describing this problem. It doesn't hold a solution but you may want to try a more recent version of jQuery of you didn't already.

Have you tried to load the file through `ajax()`? Would be longer but might work.